# YII2 Model for an OrderObject

Tags: php, model, yii2, erp

I am trying to create a high-performance model in YII2. I have 2 databases connected (MSSQSL: own and ERP-System) - it works. Now I try to load an order from the ERP system. The system distributes all order information across different tables.

table: order

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [orderid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [lastupdate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
....
```

table: order information1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Information1](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Parameter] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](255) NULL,
....
```

table: order information2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Information2](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Parameter] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](255) NULL,
....
```

I have created for all models and can also individually access the tables. In the order model, I have built a class GetInformationData:

```
public function getInformationData ()
{

    $description = Order_Information2::find()->select('Value')->where(['ID' => $this->id, 'Parameter' => 'txt_ description'])->one();
    //...
    $this->description =  !empty($description) ? $description->Value : '';
    //...
}
    //...
```

It works, but it is very slow. Each order has about 500 parameters 
and it takes half an eternity until everything is loaded ;-(

I tried to connect the model, but unfortunately without success.

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    public function getOrder_Information1()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order_Information1::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Order_Information1 extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Order::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share much details, but you can query all parameters in one query and avoid creating model (which seems to be unused, since you need only `Value`):

```
public function getInformationData () {
    $data = Order_Information2::find()
        ->select(['Parameter', 'Value'])
        ->where(['ID' => $this->id])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    foreach ($data as ['Parameter' => $parameter, 'Value' => $value]) {
        $this->$parameter = $value;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: And what `It doesn't work` actually mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hey Rob, I think the syntax is not correct: foreach ($data as ['Parameter' => $parameter, 'Value' => $value]) {

Comment: It should be fine, but you need PHP 7.1 to use it: https://3v4l.org/BRIU8

Comment: Oh, I'm using Php 7. Is there a solution here, too? Thx rob

Comment: You can use `foreach ($data as $row) { $parameter = $row['Parameter']; $value = $row['Value'];`.